# How to pass two structure variable to GOlang html template?

Tags: html, go, structure

I want to pass multiple structure variable to Golang html templates. How to do this?

I am passing users variable. Still i want to pass another variable.
How to access those variable in view file i.e. html file.

t.Execute(w, users)